# How do I make a function using multiple inputs?

Tags: matlab, function

I have to make a 50x50 matrix with random values -10 to 10, and then using a custom function called `averageColumn()`, I have to create a 1x50 matrix of the average of each column, excluding any values less than 0.

I have no problem generating the matrix, but I don't know how to make my function work. I keep receiving an error message stating that my function does not have enough input arguments.

The code I have for the function is:

```
function outputArg1 = averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2)
%inputArg1 = an m x n matrix
% inputArg2 = the column# to average
% outputArg1 = the column average, or zero if all the values happen to be zero
for rowNum = 1:50
if inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) > 0
    inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) = inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2);
else
    inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) = NaN;
end

outputArg1 = nanmean(inputArg1, inputArg2);
end
```

and the code I have for the matrix in a separate file is:

```
inputArg1 = randi([-10 10],50,50)

for inputArg2 = 1:50
    outputArg1 = averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2)    
end
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run, because there is a `rowNum` variable used in your `averageColumn` function without prior definition. Could you please fix this? Otherwise, one can hardly help you, I guess.

Comment: Edited my code to have the values of `rowNum` I need, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you be clearer on what is actually wrong? From your statement `I keep receiving an error message stating that my function does not have enough input arguments.` I get the impression that your code doesn't run at all, but it does for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Ah, I haven't seen your last edit. Just use `nanmean` than.

---

So, I tried to keep as much code of yours as possible.

First of all, let's have a look at your script calling your function:

```matlab
inputArg1 = randi([-10 10], 50, 50)

for inputArg2 = 1:size(inputArg1, 2)
    outputArg1(inputArg2) = averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2);   
end

outputArg1
```

Just a general advice: Better extract dimensions of inputs given to you instead of hard-coding values. (You set up your input yourself here, of course, but try to keep that in mind.) To create the wanted array with the averages, just use the column number from your `for` loop as an array index.

Now, let's go to your function:

```matlab
function outputArg1 = averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2)
% inputArg1 = an m x n matrix
% inputArg2 = the column# to average
% outputArg1 = the column average, or zero if all the values happen to be zero

for rowNum = 1:size(inputArg1, 1)
    if inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) < 0
        inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) = NaN;
    end
end

outputArg1 = nanmean(inputArg1(:, inputArg2));

end
```

Again, don't hard-code values (`rowNum`)! Also, the `end` for that `for` loop (your edit) was missing. The `if` statement was too complicated, since `inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2) = inputArg1(rowNum, inputArg2)` is redundant. Just set all negative inputs to `NaN`. To calculate the "average", just use the [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html#bt5b82t-1-nanflag) function using the `omitnan` flag. Or, if you have access to the "Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox", you could use the [`nanmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) function.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be working now. Turns out part of the problem was that I needed to close and reopen matlab.

Comment: You may want to try commands like clear all; close all; clc; next time to clear the workspace. Most of the time, closing and reopening Matlab solves problems because you forgot to clear some variable.

Answer (score 2):

Why is everybody iterating? Use more vectorizsation!...

And why all the NaNs? Use a positive look up!...

**My Proposal**

The Function:

```
function ret = averageCol(A, n)

ret = mean(A(A(:, n)>=0, n))

end
```

Call it

```
A = randi([-100, 100], 50);

out = arrayfun( @(n) averageCol(A, n), 1:size(A, 2))
```

---

**Explanation**

From inside to outside

[1] `A(:, n)` -- return the n-th column

[2] `[1] >= 0` -- return a boolean column vector, which can also be used for indexing

[3] `A([2], n)` -- returns all values from the n-th column that are greater or equal zero

[4] Take the average of [3]... Boom! You are there...

Comment: Good code. Personally, this looks like a higher level usage of the language than I am comfortable with, so this is why I am iterating. But I will try to understand the techniques you have used, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two more options to get the same result:

With

```
A = randi([-10, 10], 50);
```

**Solution 1: Using matrix indexing and `nanmean`**

```
A(A<0)=NaN;
out = nanmean(A);
```

**Solution 2: Using linear algeabra**

```
out = ones(1,size(A,2))*(A.*(A>=0))./sum(A>=0)
```

Where I use `X̅  =   1'*X*(1'*1)^-1`    with 1 being a `n x 1` column vector of ones

Answer (score 0):

I believe your implementation over-complicated things a little bit. Maybe you can try an easier approach.

If I have understood your requirements correctly, the below code should give you want you want. If it does not, please let me know.

Comments in the code should be enough for you to understand what is going on.

```matlab
mat = randi([-10 10],50,50); % your input matrix

sums = sum(mat); % an array that contains sums of all columns

avgMat = sums/50; % an array that contains average of each column

for i = 1:length(avgMat) % this loop removes negative averages
    if avgMat(i) < 0
        avgMat(i) = NaN;
    end
end
```

Comment: As much as I appreciate all of the effort you've put forth for me, part of the main requirement is that my function follows the parameters shown in my comments. I have to have two input arguments, each named inputArg1 and inputArg2, and my output has to be outputArg1. I apologize; I should have been more specific above.

Comment: @byetisener You are "over-complicating" things, too. Instead of looping everything try this: `avgMat(avgMat<0) = nan`... And you can use `mean` for taking the average over the columns right away.

Comment: Regardless, of whether or not byetisener is over-complicating their code, the prompt itself is over-complicated to begin with. My professor for no reason thinks that over-complicating his prompts will make us improve faster, while it's only made us struggle more lmao

Comment: Great, did not think of that at first! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Since I change the implementation quite a lot, I decided to submit this as another answer.

So I believe this is what you want, hopefully this time.

```matlab
inputArg1 = randi([-10 10],50,50);

outputArg1 = [];
for inputArg2 = 1:50
    outputArg1 = [outputArg1 averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2)];  
end
```

In the above script I have changed how you manipulate your outputArg1 in every iteration, so have a look at it. I take a value from the averegaColumn function in every iteration and add it to the outputArg array.

Be warned, chaning the size of an array like this inside a loop is bad practice!!! But then again, your question can be completed in 3-4 lines anyway :)

And here is the rest. I think the code is self-explanatory.

```matlab
function outputArg1 = averageColumn(inputArg1, inputArg2)
% inputArg1 = an m x n matrix
% inputArg2 = the column# to average
% outputArg1 = the column average, or zero if all the values happen to be zero

column = inputArg1(:,inputArg2); % take the required column from the input matrix
column(column < 0) = 0; % thanks to Sven Krüger for reminding me this usage!!!
outputArg1 = mean(column);
```

I think this is the easiest implementation that can be done using functions and multiple input arguments for this task. But of course, the power of community can find some easier solutions. Let me know, if you do not understand anything.

Comment: The bad thing about the new zeros is that they are having an impact on the average.